# Mysql sentence update one column on multiple WHERE

Tags: mysql

I need to do this.

```
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances SET user=941 WHERE uid=791;
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances SET user=54 WHERE uid=3439;
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances SET user=453 WHERE uid=945;
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances SET user=1421 WHERE uid=3219;
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances SET user=33 WHERE uid=943;
```

I need some kind of conditioning right?

Comment: Why bother?....

Comment: **Why** do you need any "conditioning"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You mean like with a loop on a script? I need to execute straight into the db. Also with a loop it will be a lot of query's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator in the `where` clause and then make the distinction using a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE tx_seminars_attendances 
SET user = CASE uid 
    WHEN  791 THEN  941
    WHEN 3439 THEN   54
    WHEN  945 THEN  453
    WHEN 3219 THEN 1421
    WHEN  943 THEN   33
END
WHERE uid in (781, 3439, 945, 3219, 943);
```

Comment: ey! Exactly that. That's new for me, thank youuuuu